# Within 6 levels is there any way to change your save DC from Wisdom to Charisma for a Cleric?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization, cleric, saving-throw, e6

I'm playing in an E6 game (caps out at level 6) and with the stats I rolled and templates I'd like to apply, I end up with a downright amazing Charisma score.

Unfortunately, I'm playing a cleric and my wisdom is kind of meh. I'm trying to change my Save DC's so that they use Charisma instead of Wisdom but I want to do this without losing access to 3rd level spells. This specific build uses a cleric, and I must take at least one level of cleric. Do you know any method not listed of making my clerical spell save DCs use Charisma?

**I already know about:**

- Dynamic Priest
- Geomancer
- Generic Spellcaster
- 3rd Party Stuff (While I didn't mention it above please don't list any 3rd party material)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Geomancer is the only published method for getting Charisma-based DCs as a Cleric.

You can enter Geomancer as a single-classed Cleric (e.g. Southern Magician feat), but then you wouldn’t actually have a Charisma-using class to use as the basis for Charisma-based DCs. The best you can do is a single level in a Charisma-based class.

But since you already knew that, the answer to your complete question is: there isn’t any.

Comment: Dynamic Priest doesn't actually affect save DC's though which is my problem. (Last line in Dynamic Priest) *Your spell save DCs are not affected by this change.*

Comment: @MrTumnus All right then, then there is literally nothing. Geomancer I’d mis-remembered, but it doesn’t help much.

Comment: Yea, I figured. I'm pretty well versed in the system myself and have been struggling to find an answer that fit. I was hoping that someone out there had a solution, oh well, thanks for the help in any case.